# Promises are behaving asynchronously I think

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I've been trying to get my head around asynchronous code made to run synchronously (or look and feel as though it is!)

**I want the counters to run one after the other, from top to bottom.**

At work they tend to just try to time things using setTimeouts and don't understand callback (neither do I for that matter) but as callbacks can be pretty complicated to chain ("callback hell" anyone?) I'm not bothering to learn them and don't care at all about legacy browser versions.

[Please take a look at my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deemyboy/dr9kon1L/6/) and you'll see what mean.

```
function runPercentCounter(ind) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var argsArray = [{
        display: '#countPercentage1 > span',
        finalVal: 90,
        tickSpeed: 20,
        fillBar: '#fillBar1',
        nextIndex: 1
      },
      {
        display: '#countPercentage2 > span',
        finalVal: 17,
        tickSpeed: 150,
        fillBar: '#fillBar2',
        nextIndex: 2
      },
      {
        display: '#countPercentage3 > span',
        finalVal: 37,
        tickSpeed: 10,
        fillBar: '#fillBar3',
        nextIndex: 'undefined'
      },
    ];

    var args = argsArray[ind]

    var fillBar = $(args.fillBar);
    var display = $(args.display);
    var currentValue = parseInt(display.text());
    $(fillBar).css('width', currentValue + '%');

    var finalVal = args.finalVal;
    var diff = finalVal - currentValue;
    var step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);

    for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        currentValue += step;
        $(fillBar).css('width', (currentValue - step) + '%');
        display.text(currentValue);
      }, args.tickSpeed * i);
      console.log(i);
    }

    var t = args.nextIndex;
    console.log(t);
    if (typeof t != "undefined") {
      resolve(t);

    } else {
      reject('End of the line!');
    }
  });
}


runPercentCounter(0)
  .then(runPercentCounter)
  .then(runPercentCounter)
  .catch(console.error());
```

[image: percent bars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow wait until your loops is done to `resolve` the promises. The way async programming in javascript works is that you will run the *whole* function, including that part where you resolve the promise *before* any of the async stuff happens. As a result your promise is resolved too soon.

The way you have things set up makes it a little hard to add an clean easy fix. You can have a less-than-clean, but still easy fix by adding a timeout set to the last loop iteration, which will delay the promise resolution until after each bar has done its thing with:

```
function runPercentCounter(ind) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var argsArray = [{
        display: '#countPercentage1 > span',
        finalVal: 90,
        tickSpeed: 20,
        fillBar: '#fillBar1',
        nextIndex: 1
    },
    {
        display: '#countPercentage2 > span',
        finalVal: 17,
        tickSpeed: 150,
        fillBar: '#fillBar2',
        nextIndex: 2
    },
    {
        display: '#countPercentage3 > span',
        finalVal: 37,
        tickSpeed: 10,
        fillBar: '#fillBar3',
        nextIndex: 'undefined'
    },
    ];

    var args = argsArray[ind]

    var fillBar = $(args.fillBar);
    var display = $(args.display);
    var currentValue = parseInt(display.text());
    $(fillBar).css('width', currentValue + '%');

    var finalVal = args.finalVal;
    var diff = finalVal - currentValue;
    var step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);

    for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        currentValue += step;
        $(fillBar).css('width', (currentValue - step) + '%');
        display.text(currentValue);
    }, args.tickSpeed * i);
    console.log(i);
    }
    // Wait the full amount before resolving
    setTimeout(function(){
        var t = args.nextIndex;
        console.log(t);
        if (typeof t != "undefined") {
        resolve(t);
    
        } else {
        reject('End of the line!');
        }
    }, args.tickSpeed * Math.abs(diff))

    
});
}


runPercentCounter(0)
.then(runPercentCounter)
.then(runPercentCounter)
.catch(console.error());
```

Here's an updated fiddle with this small change: https://jsfiddle.net/0sggcmfe/

---

#### EDIT

Here's a nicer way of dealing with this using a `setInverval()` rather than timeout. It takes the responsibility of keeping track of which bar your on away from  `runPercentageCounter` and makes the promises pattern make a little more sense:

```
var argsArray = [{
    display: '#countPercentage1 > span',
    finalVal: 90,
    tickSpeed: 20,
    fillBar: '#fillBar1',
    nextIndex: 1
},
{
    display: '#countPercentage2 > span',
    finalVal: 17,
    tickSpeed: 150,
    fillBar: '#fillBar2',
    nextIndex: 2
},
{
    display: '#countPercentage3 > span',
    finalVal: 37,
    tickSpeed: 10,
    fillBar: '#fillBar3',
    nextIndex: 'undefined'
},
];

function runPercentCounter(args) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var fillBar = $(args.fillBar);
        var display = $(args.display);
        var currentValue = parseInt(display.text());
        $(fillBar).css('width', currentValue + '%');

        var finalVal = args.finalVal;
        var diff = finalVal - currentValue;
        var step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);

        var count = 0
        var interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (count == Math.abs(diff)){
                clearInterval(interval)
                return resolve()
            }
            currentValue += step;
            $(fillBar).css('width', (currentValue - step) + '%');
            display.text(currentValue); 
            count++
        }, args.tickSpeed)        
    });
    }

argsArray.reduce((a, c) => a.then(() => runPercentCounter(c)), Promise.resolve())
```

Here's a new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/markm/rx83hacm/1/

Comment: but all this does is pause for the same time of the animation doesn't it? Not really what I was looking for. though it does give the desired effect. I could have probably done that without promises.

Comment: It pauses for the length of time of each animation so one starts after the other -- isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: yes, that is but can't that be achieved without promises?

Comment: ps. i don't mean to sound ungrateful and pleased that it works but i don't see the point of a promise chain if it needs timeouts to make it work

Comment: Promises add convenience in cases like these so you can avoid all the callbacks. You absolutely could do this with just timeouts and callbacks. They are not magic -- at some point you need to tell it when to call resolve. You could also do that inside the for loop, but you would need to check that you were on the last iteration.

Comment: Promises are just glorified callbacks. A Promise chain is just a bunch of callbacks. But the callbacks need to be triggered somehow: I/O or setTimeout calls

Comment: @deemyBoy see the edit for a cleaner way of handling this.

Comment: @MarkM thanks very much for your help - I've kind of had a break from programming but trying to get back into it - just came back to SO and signed and and doing a little house-keeping

Answer (score 0):

You are resolving your `Promise` right away, not after the animation loop has run, which is why things seem to be updated in parallel.

You could add another `setTimeout` function after your for loop that then resolves the `Promise`.

Comment: err, how about *you* try and make the change?

Comment: actually, the whole point was to move away from set timeouts. I want the counters to run one after the other because the ticker speed for each can be changed. If we manually have to calculate the time to delay then this is pointless. I wanted the  next animation to start when the previous one ended, not after a manually calculated timeout. It seems that if we use a timeout to delay the promises then we haven't really moved forward, at least not in the direction I thought we could go. Maybe I've misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: you might want to look at animation libraries that will solve all of this for you. Here's a list: https://www.sitepoint.com/our-top-9-animation-libraries/